# httpd.conf for git repo creation fails

Tags: git, apache2, redmine, ubuntu-12.04, httpd.conf

I'm trying to setup automatic git repo creation when creating a new redmine project following this tutorial: http://www.dreu.info/blog/install-redmine-with-automated-git-on-centos-redhat/

But when I add the httpd.conf into my empty httpd.conf, apache2 won't start. Can someone help me out or verify if the config is correct?

```
PerlLoadModule Apache::Redmine

SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/git/
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/
<Location /git>
        RedmineGitSmartHttp yes
        DAV on

        AuthType Basic
        Require valid-user
        AuthName "git"

        PerlAccessHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::access_handler
        PerlAuthenHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::authen_handler

        RedmineDSN "DBI:mysql:database=redmine_databse;host=localhost"
        RedmineDbUser "user"
        RedmineDbPass "password"

</Location>

Alias /git-private /var/git

<Location /git-private>

        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all

        <Limit GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>

                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                Allow from 127.0.0.1
                Allow from localhost
        </Limit>
</Location>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.
The path to git-http-backend was incorrect.
to find the correct path I used 'find / -name git-http-backend" and changed the path to: /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for decision.

Myself too encountered with similar problem.
After upgrade CentOS up to 5.10, 'git packages' were the new place:

```
    ls -1 /usr/bin/git-*|head -5
    /usr/bin/git-add
    /usr/bin/git-add--interactive
    /usr/bin/git-am
    /usr/bin/git-annotate
    /usr/bin/git-apply
```